# Convert __m128d to double

Tags: c++, sse

I just try to use SSE extensions, and I started with a simple vector dot multiplication.
So I wrote the following code:

```
void SSE_vectormult(double * A, double * B)
{
    __m128d a;
    __m128d b;
    a = _mm_load_pd(A);
    b = _mm_load_pd(B);
    const int mask = 0xf1;
    __m128d res = _mm_dp_pd(a,b,mask);
    A = res;
}
```

with `A` and `B` vectors of the same length. Now, I have to convert the result in `__m128d` back into `double`. Is there a easy way to do this (or a conversion function)?
Thank you!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The counterpart of `load` would be `store`[[ms](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2zzyyy1b%28v=vs.90%29.aspx), [intel](http://software.intel.com/sites/products/documentation/studio/composer/en-us/2011Update/compiler_c/intref_cls/common/intref_sse2_fp_store.htm)]. So in your case I'd guess (double precision, aligned pointer, regular store):

```
_mm_store_pd(A, res); //A = res;
```

Answer (score 9):

You should use `double dot = _mm_cvtsd_f64(res)`.  This extracts the lower 64bit double from the 128 bit register.